# Odd "Darkening" Of Faces

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm working on a project for school, where I need to make a 3D model of a castle. I have the castle's basic details pretty much complete now, but I've noticed there are weird shadowy bits/faces that are darker than others.
Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

I've also tried recalculating the normals, the previous image above was with Normals recalculated outside, here's an example with them recalculated inside, the problem still persists:

[image]

Comment: What method did you use to texture the castle? Did you use texture painting, or did you individually texture the vertices? Also, I see that you are using Eevee render. Try using cycles render with something like a sun or hemisphere lamp pointed to the dark areas.

Comment: You may want to add an extra lamp unless the darkening is caused by the texture, in which case you should check the texturing for overlapping faces, or vertices.

Comment: I used Poliigon, and found textures. I assigned materials to the entire faces.

And ok, I'll try using Cycles render.

Ok, so rendering with Cycles almost seems to be making it worse.

Like, the effect is amplified.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. I'm pretty sure there aren't any overlapping faces or anything, as I tried deleting the faces of one of the worst/ mostly-affected areas, and it didn't have anything behind it, and I don't see any z-fighting just rotating around the model and whatnot.

Comment: Ok, it also seems as if applying Shade Flat to it fixes the problem, like, maybe 95% is gone, however, as soon as I choose Shade Smooth, (which is what I had it set to before), it has the shading problem.

Comment: Add a couple sub-surfaces, and you shouldn't need to add smooth shading.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll do that right now.